# How can I prepare for blockchain developer interviews/solidity?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I'm a front-end developer who migrated into "web3" 8 months ago, I consider myself as a junior in the blockchain field, I've worked on several NFTS and web3 projects as a freelancer, I've gained experience, I've prepared my portfolio, and my Github account in order to start looking for a full-time remote job as a full-stack blockchain developer(solidity, hardhat, web3, NextJs, React, IFPS).
I would like to know how can I prepare myself for potential interviews in this field?
Do you have any resources or advice to share to prepare for solidity and EVM interviews?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a number of interviews in last two months. And none of them was live coding one. Rather, its one of two things.

1. They just send you a task to do. (Often with no live interview prior). These I refuse on the spot. Because If your developer can't spend 30min to talk to me, then I sure as hell will not spend my weekend doing task for you. (It's just not that kind of a market)
2. You have one or two experienced developers asking you questions. Most often about ETH and Solidity in general.

Some of the questions I got:

(1) What is EVM

(2) What is ABI

(3) Explain Gas

(4) If I send first transaction, followed by a second one 5 seconds later. Which of those transactions will be mined first.

(5). What is ERC20 token

(6). What is NFT /What is
ERC1155/ERC721

(7). Solidity (private/public/internal/external)-->Explain

(8). memory vs data

(9). pure vs view

(10). fallback() vs receive()

(11). Explain call, static call, delegateCall.

(12). What are ways/tricks you know for saving gas.

(13). gas limit vs block gas limit

(14). What is nonce (this I noticed many developers, even senior ones have hard time explaining, not sure why)

(15). How would you create upgradable smartContracts. (Proxy pattern is usually the answer they are looking for here)

(16). Address vs PublicKey vs PrivateKey (Explain what is what)

(17). What is r,s,v (Eth signature)

All in all there are number of good "interview videos". Eat the Block has video going through 100 most often questions for Solidity developers. [100 Solidity interview questions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoCM07HlfhU&t=806s)

I would also recommend reading ETH yellow paper for deeper understanding. (If you have time, it's not as light read) [ETH Yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

NOTE: I knew answers to all of those questions just from experience gained from current project I had been employed at for the last 17 months (had no Blockchain experience prior to it).

Comment: Can you please share with us the websites that you used to find jobs as a blockchain developer?

Comment: @DavidJay I only used LinkedIn. The number of recruiters contacting you will likely be so high (If you have any Blockchain experience) that you will have to refuse interviews with most of them. But you can also search for job postings there too.